# Copy line matching pattern in multiple files to a new file

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have 200 output files, of which I need to compare one line.
The exact line varies, but `Total Energy = xyz` always exists.
Is there an easy way to copy that line from my output files in a new file? I'm using Ksh, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

`grep` is the simplest command for this.

Assuming you have files in one folder then

`grep 'Total Energy =' dir/* > results.txt`

Without more information on the way your files are named / organized, I can't be more precise. Hopefully this will let you solve it

Other solutions might use `sed` or `awk`, but `grep` is probably the simplest